# profiles in Sitecore DMS 2.0

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms

I'm just getting started on Sitecore DMS 2.0, and not sure if I understand how the profiles work.

I'm trying to have a page that will show different info depending on if you're just a regular visitor or belong to a specified profile.

I've created a persona, Marketing person, with a maximum score of 10. I've then created a few pages that gives different scores (3, 4, and 4) to the Marketing persona if you view them. I thought that these were cumulative, i.e. if you viewed all three pages your total score for the Marketing persona would be 10, and if you then view the page with the profile dependent content you would see the content for that profile. However, it seems like it's only keeping the score for the last page. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**: My condition is: In the rule set editor under Profiles and Patterns I've chosen "where the value of Marketing person profile key is greater than or equal to 10".

Thanks,

Annelie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug in Sitecore. From the release notes: "The scores for profile keys were not summed correctly. In many cases, each profile key would contain the value of the last assigned score instead of the sum of all previously assigned scores. (348298)".

If anyone else comes across this, the version it was fixed in is Sitecore CMS 6.5.0 rev. 110818 (6.5.0 Update-1) and DMS 2.0.0 rev. 110818.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, but might be misunderstanding a part of it, or maybe you need to give us more info.

If the persona is set to have a max value of 10, then you can get **up to** 10 points for it per page. Hitting pages of 3, 4, and 4 values will indeed give you 10 points, but the conditional content shows based on its own rule. You need to look at the rule you've set for your conditional content to see what it has for conditions. Here's an example:

> If the value of the profile key **Marketing person** *is greater than or
>   equal* to *10*, *set the datasource* to
>   *`/sitecore/content/home/some-marketing-data-item`*

Comment: This is exactly what I've done. In the rule set editor under Profiles and Patterns I've chosen "where the value of Marketing person profile key is greater than or equal to 10". Still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I've set the data source to be the Marketing page (i.e. I've clicked the Personalize Content browse button and browsed to the page I want to show. I don't know where you can see the rule spelt out like that, this is doing it from Presentation -> Details -> Edit Layout Details -> choose the control then click Personalize). If I set the value to be 10 for a page then it works fine, it just doesn't seem to accumulate the values.

Comment: So if you clear cookies and set a single page to 10, after visiting it the component data changes? But setting it to low values and hitting the page multiple times doesn't affect it?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happens.